Download binary file to MCU with STM32CudeIDE
I have .bin file. How can I download this to microcontroller using stm32CubeIDE.
I have tried to change .elf to .bin in Run configuration.
 Error: Failed to execute MI command ... not in executable format: file format not recognized. 


Why are you trying to do this? STM32CubeProgrammer is a better tool that will let you program a .bin file.
